# Received a message saying Western Union received $600 from Mastercard- I assumed a scam- how does it work?

Tags: scams

My parents live in Australia and they emailed me to say they received an automated message that $631 from Mastercard. Western Union- that is an instant red flag as scam but how it is supposed work?

Comment: Does it really matter? Most likely they would need to provide a bank account which the scammers would then try to hijack, or they would be given a forged check and then asked for the money back under this or that pretense, or they'd be skimmed for a COT or some other "pay me to pay you" scheme, possibilities are endless.

Comment: It is an automated message which no contact details.

Comment: If in any doubt contact Mastercard and/or Western Union directly and ask them to verify, of course -- NOT using any address or phone number in the message; look those up yourself.

Comment: one way that's popularly exposed on youtube at the moment (but people still fall for) is they trick you into doing some weird computer stuff where you type in the number 631 and they add some extra zeroes, then they trick you into thinking your refund was actually $63100 and you have to send them back $62469 so they don't lose their job